# Copied XPATH doesn't work in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, webdriver

I have tried to scrape my school's website and it's not working. I tried a lot of stuff but on most of the time the XPATH that I passed was incorrect. (the XPATH was copied from the HTML) There are a lot of elements like this that aren't responding after clicking or they just can't be find.
My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def element(driver, by_x, html_element):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((by_x, html_element))
        )
        return element
    except:
        print("Element not found")

class EduPage:
    def __init__(self, name, password, edu_link):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
        PATH = "C:\Programming Modules\Drivers\chromedriver.exe"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, options=options)
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.driver.get(edu_link)

    def log_in(self):
        login_name = element(self.driver, By.ID, "login_Login_1e1")
        login_name.send_keys(self.name)
        login_pass = element(self.driver, By.ID, "login_Login_1e2")
        login_pass.send_keys(self.password, Keys.RETURN)

    def go_to_class(self):
        online_class = element(self.driver, By.XPATH, "//*[@id='jwb98b9ff6_md']/div/div[2]")
        online_class.click()


edupage = EduPage("my name", "my password", "https://gymstrop.edupage.org/login/")
edupage.log_in()
edupage.go_to_class
```

HTML code (I want to click the highlighted element)
[image: HTML]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is failing because `parent element` **id** `attribute` is **dynamic**. I would suggest use following `xpath` to identify the element..

```
//div[@class='userTopOnlineLesson']/a
```

so your code would be like

```
online_class = element(self.driver, By.XPATH, "//div[@class='userTopOnlineLesson']/a")
```

---

Or following css selector.

```
div.userTopOnlineLesson>a.userTopBlackboard
```

Comment: @themm1 : what error are you getting? timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by KunduK should work and if it is not working, I also would like to see the actual selenium error that you are getting.

Meanwhile could you please try to increase the wait time to 60, just to figure out if that has nothing to do long waiting time

```
try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((by_x, html_element))
        )
        return element
    except:
        print("Element not found")
```